# "Nesting functions" in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a beginner's question. I thought I can nest functions in scala like this:

```
myString.replaceAll("a", "b") { replacedStr1 =>
  replacedStr1.replaceAll("c", "d") }
```

But it gives me "Missing parameter type:replacedStr1" error at replacedStr1.

Comment: Did you mean to do this: `myString.replaceAll("a","b").replaceAll("c","d")`? That is, chaining, not nesting.

Answer (score 0):

you're trying something too complicated, just call replaceAll twice:

```
"acacacacacac".replaceAll("a", "b").replaceAll("c", "d")
```

In your example, you:

1. replace all "a" by "b" in `myString`
2. define a function ??? => _.replaceaLL("c","d")

What you put in curly bracket is a function definition for which you forgot to give the type of the input argument `replacedStr1`. That's what the error message is about. If you where to write:

```
{ replacedStr1: String => replacedStr`.replaceAll("c","d") }
```

It would compile. However this function would be defined but not be used.